# EF6 - Entity not part of my context?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

My database has 2 contexts pointing to it.
These contexts are, so far, completely apart. My problem is that, I can't use the second context... It gets created fine, all tables there and etc, but whenever I query it, boom!

Details:
Heres the context:

```
public class ServiceSupportDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ServiceSupportDbContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }
    public ServiceSupportDbContext() { }
    public DbSet<ImportItem> ImportItems { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the entity:

```
[Table("DIPItems")]
public class ImportItem
{
    internal string ExceptionMessage { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ContextId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public string LastKnownHost { get; set; }
    public string DocumentJson { get; set; }
    public string SourceFilePath { get; set; }
    public string DestinationFilePath { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string FullExceptionMessage
    {
        get
        {
            return ExceptionMessage;
        }
        set
        {
            ExceptionMessage = (ExceptionMessage == null ? value : ExceptionMessage + "\r\n" + value);
        }
    }
    public ImportItemStatus Status { get; set; }
    public int RetryCount { get; set; }
    public int ProcessId { get; set; }
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] ConcurrencyCheck { get; set; }
}

[Flags]
public enum ImportItemStatus
{
    Waiting = 0,
    Copying = 1,
    Copied = 3,
    ExtractingContent = 4,
    ContentExtracted = 12,
    Indexing = 16,
    Indexed = 48,
    Hashing = 64,
    Hashed = 192,
    Error = -1
}
```

As you can see this context is pretty simple and things should be working fine, but i dont know why, I keep hitting the "The entity type is not part of the model for the current context" wall...

Anyone know how to troubleshoot this? maybe solve this mess?

**EDIT 1:**
Seed runs fine too...

Comment: How are using the context? I can see that there is an empty constructor for the context, do you need that?

Comment: @AlanMacgowan the empty constructor is not used...

Answer (score 0):

Put this on your custom DBContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ImportItem>().ToTable("ImportItem");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I didn't noticed that the connection string being used was a EF old-style conn string... it was pointing to an old, but still existing model...